# Intellij doesn't closes the messaging

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated Intellij to new version ... after that it says Enable Lombok and restart ... and a closing project appears and stands forever

ps -e | grep intel* doesn't work

I can't find any intellij process running

I have to reboot my machine to bypass this.

My old version was ok for Lombo

Answer (score 0):

You can try this shell command to find the process to kill it:
`ps -ef | grep idea`
.

Also, you could try to select `Help | Find Action` from the main menu, type `Registry...`, select it, and in the opened list, find and disable the `ide.await.scope.completion` option here to workaround this issue.